# how to find longest common substring for 2 arrays with binary numbers.?

Tags: image, image-processing, uiimageview, digit

how to find longest common substring in case of two arrays with binary numbers.Let, x=[1 0 1 0], y= [0 1 1 0 1 1]then 1 0 1 of x are same in 1 0 1 of y in 3rd,4th,5th, positoin. how to find  the perecentage of x are matching so here it is,75%,and also the index of y where it started matching ,in this case the starting index is 3.

Comment: How is it related to image-processing?

Comment: Using Image steganography.

Comment: I assume your arrays are quite long then